# Downloading list of images to Bitmap array C#

Tags: c#, image, xaml, windows-8

There is a component in my app where certain images need to be preloaded. My thoughts are that I should donwload all the images from the web into Bitmap objects and then use those as source  in my Images. What is the easiest way to do this? I have written a bit of code to download images already, but it doesn't seem to work with multiple images:

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        NetResult result;

        try
        {

            Debug.WriteLine("Starting call to " + Url);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(Url);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            result = await this.processContent(response.Content);

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {

            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Debug.WriteLine("Unable to load " + Url);
            result = new NetResult(NetResultStatus.Failure, "Could not connect to " + Url + ".");

}
```

...

and ProcessContent works like this:

```
public override async Task<NetResult> processContent(HttpContent content)
    {

        InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = null;

        if (content != null && !Constants.FakeInternet)
        {
            byte[] img = await content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            // Transform to a stream
            randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(randomAccessStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0));
            writer.WriteBytes(img);
            await writer.StoreAsync();
        }

        _m = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        (Application.Current as App).UIDispatcher.DispatchAsync(() =>
            {


                    // Create bitmap image
                    image = new BitmapImage();

                    NetImage i = (NetImage)this;

                    Debug.WriteLine("Creating Image " + Url);
                    image.ImageFailed += ImageFailed;
                    image.ImageOpened += ImageOpened;
                    image.SetSource(randomAccessStream);


            });

        _m.WaitOne();


        return await base.processContent(content);

    }

    void ImageOpened(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Debug.WriteLine("Image opened: " + Url);
        _m.Set();

    }

    void ImageFailed(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Debug.WriteLine("Image failed: " + Url);
        image = null;
        ConnectionState = ConnectionState.Failed;
        _m.Set();

    }
```

Is there perhaps a built-in API I can use to download PNGs from the net into Bitmap objects? I guess one of the annoying things was that I have to decode the Bitmap on the UI thread... why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a WinRT API which will save you some steps in downloading the PNG and creating a BitmapImage.  That doesn't mean that one doesn't exist.

You might find it helpful to look at Scenario 4 in the [XAML Images Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/0f5d56ae-5e57-48e1-9cd9-993115b027b9).  It asynchronously computes a fractal on a background thread, and then displays the results in a WriteableBitmap.  This will get you off the UI thread.

Comment: thanks, that's at least semi-helpful :) not having to be on the UI thread simplifies some of the stuff with the dispatcher and the manualresetevent which might mess things up when i attempt to download more than one image at the same time.